# Two columns - with one side having more info on multiple lines

Tags: css

I am getting a little confused by this.

Currently have a table, with two columns.

On the left we have a description, and on the right a fact.

The left hand side is usually one line, but might wrap over onto two.

The right hand side is often 3, 4 or more lines.

How can I arrange this using CSS instead of tables.

Obviously the two sides have to line up for each row of information.

```
desc1        fact 1
desc2        fact 2
             more to fact 2
desc3        fact 3
```

etc.

Comment: Tell me, why don't you want to use tables? You can easially align the `desc2` to the middle.

Comment: I thought that tables were bad?  Everything should be css?  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Do not worry, tables aren't bad for this example. You use tabular-data, so don't mind using it. I suggest you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html and http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/ . Also just make it work. If nobody is complaining, why should you?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

HTML

```
<ul class="sublist">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Description 1</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sublist">
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Description 2 / Description 2 / Description 2 / Description 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sublist">
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Description 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.sublist > li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQp7f/)